# Apple development Certificate and development profile issues

Tags: ios, certificate

I am trying to make an app development certificate and provision profile to test with our development team on developer.apple.com.
At present, it doesnt allows me to create App development certificate.  The option is greyed out this was 2 days back.

Today, again i tried, then the option for iOS App Development is coming and the moment i go ahead, it goes to loading and never ends ???
This is very strange and for the first time in 3 years.

Moreover, when i go and create development provision profile, it takes the certificate to include and devices. The[image: n], it goes to loading and never ends. 
Whereas, it creates distribution profile easily.

Can anybody help me on this.

Comment: Perhaps there are some agreements you have left to accept?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Follow the following steps,and it should work!

- (1) Revoke all developer certificates.
- (2) Click certificated again to refresh

Cheers!